# Oozie String wf:errorCode(String node) how to check empty?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have an action node named 'CW', after that I placed a Decision Node to check if 'CW' returns error or not.... how should I write the predicate?

I tried:

`${ wf:errorCode('CW') eq '' }` then go to Y

`${ wf:errorCode('CW') != '' }` then go to N

Although it return empty string (no error), but it always goes to `N`. Any advise? Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
${not empty wf:errorCode('CW')}
```

to detect failures

Answer (score 2):

This is the only method for checking an empty string that worked for me.

```
<decision name='decision-action'>
    <switch>
        <case to='success-action'>${firstNotNull(wf:lastErrorNode(), 'no error') eq 'no error'}</case>
        <default to='failed-action' />
    </switch>
</decision>
```

So, to relate this answer directly to the question, this conditional

```
${firstNotNull(wf:errorCode('CW'), 'no error') eq 'no error}
```

should map to Y.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use the ok and error action transitions to do this?

```
<action name="CW">

    <!--
      ....
    -->

    <ok to="Y"/>
    <error to="N"/>
<\action>
```

Comment: I know about this, but alternatively I am using Hue, just want to know about how to compare the "empty String" that returned by Oozie.

Comment: And besides, **Although it return empty string (no error) it always goes to Y** - this is your defined condition logic, if it went to N then it is not functioning as expedted !?

Comment: Thanks Chris, but `${ wf:errorCode('CW') is empty }` didn't work. I don't think there is something named "is empty". It goes to why because I added that two condition... which means I didn't verify the return value correctly.

`Encountered "is", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||", "?"]`

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
${ wf:errorCode('CW') == null }
```

You can also check if CW exits with error like:

```
${ wf:lastErrorNode()=='CW' }
```

right after CW completion.

Answer (score 0):

```
${ wf:errorCode('CW') eq null } then go to Y

${ wf:errorCode('CW') != null } then go to N
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

${wf:lastErrorNode() eq wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())} --> consider this condition as success, these two values are blank when job fails
 ${wf:lastErrorNode() != wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())} --> consider this condition as failure, when jobs fails, these values do not match
it worked for me, hope this helps